# Configure the maxRequestLength parameter in system.web / httpRuntime using PowerShell commands

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, server

I'm trying to implement a script that automatically configures some properties of the IIS:

`Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Location $_ -Filter "system.webServer/asp/limits" -Name "maxRequestEntityAllowed" -Value 20000000` this command to modify maxRequestEntityAllowed works correctly

`Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Location $_ -Filter "system.web/httpRuntime" -Name "maxRequestLength" -Value 1234` This command to modify maxRequestLength does not work.

for me of the two commands it seems to me the same and correct. Could you tell me what am I wrong?
Thank you all

Comment: I have a script doing something very similar except I use the `-PSPath` parameter and the `IIS:\` provider.  Happy to post it, but can you tell me what error you are getting with the second command?

Comment: No error, it simply does not change the parameter value. It is not a question of auttorizazzioni as the scrip is launched as a system administrator

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll make a difference, but in my Exchange environment, I'm using commands like: `Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync'  -Filter "system.web/httpRuntime" -Name "maxRequestLength" -Value xxxxx` The only difference I see is specifying the location with the `-PSPath` parameter instead of `-Location`.